# How To Compile The Computation Of Cumulative Returns

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, finance

I'm trying to compile this function, specifically the second line which computes the cumulative return of 100 daily returns.

```
ty = 1 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[.01, .005], 100];
Table[ty[[i]] = ty[[i]]*ty[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length[ty]}]
```

Doing this doesn't work

```
cf = Compile[{{ty, _Real, 1}}, Table[ty[[i]] = ty[[i]]*ty[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length[ty]}]]
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Return `FoldList[Times,ty]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the only problem is that you try to modify the input array which is not supported by `Mathematica`'s `CompiledFunction` (because `Mathematica`'s general philosophy is that all objects are supposed to be immutable). Just make a copy, operate on that one, and return it:

```
cf = Compile[{{ty, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{r = ty},
   Do[r[[i]] = r[[i]]*r[[i - 1]], {i, 2, Length[r]}];
   r
   ]
  ]
```

If you want to do pass-by-reference, you can achieve that with LibraryLink. But learning how to do that is probably not worth for your use case. (I can show how to do it, though, if you like.)

Comment: Library link is if I have code written in another language and I'd like to link it up to Mathematica? So the key to getting my original compile to work was putting my variable inside a Block function first?

Comment: LibraryLink allows you to write a library in C++ and to link it dynamically into the `Mathematica` session.

Comment: " So the key to getting my original compile to work was putting my variable inside a Block function first?" Yes, declare a local variable (`r` in this case) and copy the input to it (by using `=`). Then the local variable can be modified in-place.